# How to burn arduino bootloader on SAMD21 chips using J-Link mini

Tags: samd21g

I am planning on making my own custom PCB of a SAMD21 board. I would like to ask if anyone has experience uploading arduino bootloader on a [J-link Mini](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Segger-Microcontroller/80891?qs=sGAEpiMZZMve4%2FbfQkoj%252BGJy0Rcfgzx64YhEx8e9g%2FU=) although adafruit has a [guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/69849) on this device, its not uploading a arduino bootloader.

On a related note which pins should I connect it to my SAMD21 chip ?

Comment: SWD pins. see the schematic of some SAMD21 Arduino. the connection is same for any bootloader or application upload. it is used for debugging too.

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=636902.0

Comment: on the github guide he posted, it does not mention on how to upload the arduino bootloader sadly. But thank you for telling me  SWD pins are standard on most applications

Comment: I did it in Arduino IDE. I selected the Atmel EDBG programmer and then Burn Bootloader. all SAMD programmers use the same protocol

Comment: @Juraj the Atmel EDBG would work for Arduino Zero since that has the EDBG chip.     With Jlink, I usually use Atmel Studio. Once the Jlink is connected to the chip via SWD, just goto the programmer option in Atmel Studio, select the chip and programmer and burn the programmer. It is pretty straightforward. There is a nice tutorial [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/how-to-program-samd-bootloaders/programming-the-bootloader-with-atmel-studio) which walks through it.

Comment: @karan, it worked with NXP LPC-Link2. IDE calls openocd and the programmer is configured in openocd

Comment: Hey guys post your comment as answers, so i can mark them as correct when my jlink arrives. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 1):

The Atmel EDBG would work for Arduino Zero since that has the EDBG chip. With Jlink, you can use Atmel Studio. Once the Jlink is connected to the chip via the 10 pin SWD header, goto the programmer option in Atmel Studio, select the chip and programmer and burn your firmware with the selected programmer. You can follow a tutorial [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/how-to-program-samd-bootloaders/programming-the-bootloader-with-atmel-studio) which walks through it.